# C++ SFML 2 Text not updating as expected

Tags: c++

I'm new to SFML and I'm trying to make simple game, but I have a problem:

I have Text class that handles my Score, here is the .h file

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Text
{
  public:
Text();
Text(std::string, std::string, sf::Vector2f position, int);
~Text();


void ModifyScoreBy(int value);

void Update();

void Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window);

static int getScore();



private:

sf::Text text;
sf::Font* font;
std::string pathToFont;
std::string textString;

static int numberScore;


};
```

and the .cpp file:

```
#include "Text.h"


int Text::numberScore = 0;

Text::Text()
{

}

Text::Text(std::string pathToFolder, std::string Text, sf::Vector2f position, int      numberScore)
{
font = new sf::Font;

if (!font->loadFromFile(pathToFolder))
    system("pause");


textString = Text;
this->numberScore = numberScore;
textString += std::to_string(numberScore);
text.setString(textString);
text.setFont(*font);
text.setPosition(position);
 }


 Text::~Text()
 {
 }

  int Text::getScore()
  {
return numberScore;
  }


  void Text::ModifyScoreBy(int value)
  {
numberScore += value;
  }

  void Text::Update()
  {
std::cout <<"Score: " << numberScore << std::endl;
textString = "Score: " + std::to_string(numberScore);
  }

  void Text::Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window)
  {
window.draw(text);
  }
```

the stuff with iostream is for testing purposes.

the sf::Text and the sf::Font are initialized as it should but in the Update() function it doesn't really update the sf::Text it stays Score: 0 when it is supposed to be Score: 10 or Score: 20 etc.

std::cout <<"Score: " << numberScore << std::endl; in the Update() function is working OK and is printing the right result.

I can't figure out what the problem is so I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add `text.setString(textString);` at the end of Update() (right after modifying `textString`).

Also, `numberScore` should probably not be a static variable and `font` is never freed.

Comment: Still not working after adding text.setString(textString);

About numberScore I also thing that it should not be a static variable, but I don't know why it wasn't working well(when it was not static, after using ModifyScoreBy(for ex. 10) function instead of adding 10 to the previous score it was just setting it to 10 every time) so I made it static and it fixed the problem.

However, thanks for the help!